# PHP Email sending. Works on http://localhost/ but not on http://{IP ADDRESS}/

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter

I am using this code for sending email from localhost. Its in codeIgniter. My OS is Ubuntu 14.XX

```
function email()
    {
        $config = array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
        'smtp_port' => 465,
        'smtp_user' => '*****@gmail.com', // change it to yours
        'smtp_pass' => '*****', // change it to yours
        'mailtype' => 'html',
        'charset' => 'UTF-8',
        );

        $message = 'aggasdgsd';
        $this->load->library('email', $config);
        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
        $this->email->from('*****@gmail.com'); // change it to yours
        $this->email->to('****@gmail.com');// change it to yours
        $this->email->subject('Rdfgsdfgf ing');
        $this->email->message($message);
        if($this->email->send())
       {
        echo 'Email sent.';
       }
       else
      {
       show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
      }
    }
```

Email gets delivered when I use URL `http://localhost/ci_project/email` BUT
It doesn’t work if I use URL `http://10.10.10.XX/ci_project/email`, Also there is no error message.

Have any idea, Why it is working when use localhost in URL & Not working when i use IP address in URL ??

Comment: Yes, its local. I am working on localhost.

Comment: if you `echo` something, does that work? anything in `/var/log/apache2/error.log` ? maybe it's an apache config problem

Answer (score 1):

Check if there is email server working on server or not. if you are using sendmail then try this command on server
service sendmail restart

Answer (score 0):

Is ssl enable on your PHP config?
check if you have the following line in your php.ini

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```